# matlab get mouse coordinates on image without clicking (on mouse over)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, mousemove, mouse-coordinates, mousemotionevent

I've been googling for a while to find a solution to this apparently simple problem: getting mouse coordinates in image axes while the mouse is moving (without clicking).

1. I've found that `impixelinfoval` does exactly this but I'm not able to extract the pixel coordinates from this `uicontrol` in the script (are they stored in some field?).
2. I've also found that `ginput` gives you the coordinates but only if you click.

Do you know any workaround for one of these two issues?

Are you aware of any solution to accomplish this using MATLAB functions?

Comment: you need to define a call back and query the `'CurrentPoint'` property. See [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97563-how-do-i-continuously-read-the-mouse-position-as-the-mouse-is-moving-without-a-click-event).

Comment: It works, thank you very much. Indeed I found that also getting the field 'String' from the uicontrol impixelinfoval gives you the coordinates (although you need to extract them from the string).

Comment: feel free to post a full answer to your question according to your finding, so future SO users will also benefit from what you've just learned.

Comment: A more generally robust way I feel is to use the WindowButtonMotionFcn callback within the figure, then there is no need to extract anything from strings or any other craziness :) - I added a full answer below

Answer (score 0):

Check out this callback for the figure window:
**WindowButtonMotionFcn** - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html (you do have to scroll down a decent amount, sorry about that)

This function will fire every time the mouse moves anywhere within the figure. From there, you need to make a call to get the 'CurrentPoint' of the axis you want. If the currentpoint is within the axis bounds, then you know that your mouse is over the axis and currentpoint tells you, well the current point :)

If you are not in the axis, your ButtonMotionFcn will quickly exist and so performance won't be affected noticeably.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can use it for any axes all within the same function.

Comment: The page above has been deleted :(